# installing sass for the first time

Tags: ruby, compilation, sass

I have just bought a new mac and installed mavericks.
i have used SASS many times at work and love it but I am terrible with the setup.
I'm using compass through terminal in CODA.2  and it is watching the files but does not seem to be noticing any changes, and no error messages when I deliberately brake the code.
I did some research before hand and download xcode, homebrew, ruby gems , sass and then compass. Does anyone have a solid way of installing sass+compass with ease for a rookie?

Would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: What steps did you go through?  Have you tried running Sass or Compass using a standard terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed installed xcode, homebrew then ruby, then gem and compass all through standard terminal. Can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try *running* Sass/Compass via standard terminal, though?